# C++11 std::vector in concurrent environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++11, segmentation-fault

I had an issue (segfault) running a multithreaded code in C++11. Here it is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

std::vector<int> values;
int i;

void values_push_back()
{
    values.push_back(i);
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            std::thread t(values_push_back);
            threads.push_back(std::move(t));
        }
        for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
            threads[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here the backtrace on gdb: http://pastebin.com/5b5TN70c

What's wrong in that?

Comment: Please see my comment on hmjds answer and don't blindly copy his code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is unrelated to moving.

Multiple threads are executing `vector::push_back()` on the same `vector` but
`vector::push_back()` is not threadsafe. The modifications to the `vector` need to be synchronized.

A [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) could be used to synchronize the calls to `push_back()`:

```
std::vector<int> values;
std::mutex values_mutex;

void values_push_back()
{
    values_mutex.lock();
    values.push_back(i);
    values_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Also, the variable `i` is being shared among threads without synchronization which is will result in a race condition (a possible outcome of this is duplicate `int`s added to the `vector`). Consider passing the `int` value as an argument to the thread to avoid this:

```
std::vector<int> values;
std::mutex values_mutex;

void values_push_back(int i)
{
    values_mutex.lock();
    values.push_back(i);
    values_mutex.unlock();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread(values_push_back, i));
}

for (auto& t: threads) t.join();
```

---

As commented by [bamboon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893693/bamboon) prefer [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to ensure the lock is released if `push_back()` throws (which in this case could only be `bad_alloc()` but if the `vector` changes to hold more complex objects that have throwing constructors it becomes more important):

```
void values_push_back(int i)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(values_mutex);
    values.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: I had a more complex issue I can't reproduce with a simple code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your code is not exception-safe. If push_back throws, you will deadlock, use `std::lock_guard` instead.

Comment: also consider  #include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp> AND boost::lockfree::queue <int> values {100};